# How to compare changes in data profiles over time?

Tags: r

Say , I have datasets

```
df1=
structure(list(date = c("17.02.2021", "04.11.2020", "14.11.2020", 
"24.11.2020", "29.11.2020", "04.12.2020", "09.12.2020"), x1 = c(0L, 
0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), x2 = c(674L, 632L, 1036L, 656L, 736L, 
762L, 698L), x3 = c(698L, 712L, 1140L, 704L, 784L, 786L, 722L
), x4 = c(522L, 472L, 988L, 464L, 608L, 578L, 514L), x5 = c(2408L, 
3256L, 2840L, 2840L, 2888L, 2632L, 2648L), x6 = c(1952L, 2336L, 
2480L, 2208L, 2208L, 2144L, 2016L), x7 = c(1056L, 1120L, 1504L, 
1056L, 1184L, 1184L, 1120L), x8 = c(1984L, 2464L, 2400L, 2144L, 
2208L, 2144L, 2080L), x9 = c(2336L, 2976L, 2784L, 2464L, 2784L, 
2528L, 2400L), x10 = c(2528L, 3232L, 3104L, 2848L, 2912L, 2592L, 
2656L), x11 = c(1248L, 1312L, 1504L, 1312L, 1312L, 1312L, 1248L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

each row it is date. for the first day data profile here
[image]

The second day has data profiles
[image]

and so on.

Here  reference dataset

```
df2=structure(list(date = c("06.11.2019", "01.12.2019", "25.01.2020", 
"04.02.2020", "09.02.2020", "14.02.2020"), x1 = c(12L, 0L, 1L, 
6L, 23L, 1L), x2 = c(1272L, 1046L, 688L, 572L, 592L, 328L), x3 = c(1032L, 
974L, 736L, 780L, 800L, 568L), x4 = c(792L, 862L, 496L, 476L, 
592L, 296L), x5 = c(2232L, 1496L, 1784L, 2792L, 3064L, 3544L), 
    x6 = c(2976L, 1904L, 1632L, 1760L, 1376L, 1440L), x7 = c(1568L, 
    1248L, 1008L, 1120L, 992L, 800L), x8 = c(1888L, 1376L, 1632L, 
    2400L, 2464L, 2720L), x9 = c(2080L, 1504L, 1760L, 2848L, 
    2912L, 3296L), x10 = c(2400L, 1552L, 1824L, 2848L, 2928L, 
    3360L), x11 = c(2400L, 1504L, 1120L, 1040L, 784L, 736L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Is there a way or method that would compare the profile of each row of data in df1 with the reference dataset df2, if the profile is similar, then 1 otherwise 0

The date in both dataset can be different, the main problem is detect is profiles are similar or not.

My desired output. The Peter's code is good, but is it possible calculate The difference between profiles by variables for example
[image]

Comment: How do you define similar?

Comment: What is the expected output for the data shared?

Comment: Your plots are calculated taking the mean of x1, x2 etc irrespective of the dates(There is no time dimension) but your question says otherwise. It's not very clear what your expectation is? Thanks

Comment: @Ronak Shah , i edited with desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code allows you to visually compare the reference and `df1` profiles. As you can see that none of the profiles match exactly. Some profiles are similar, but without a definition of "similar" as pointed out by @user2974951 it's difficult to move this closer to an answer.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)


# restructure the data to allow comparison between the datasets

df <- 
  expand.grid("date_ref" = df2$date, "date_df1" = df1$date) %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("date_ref" = "date")) %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = c("date_df1" = "date")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("x"), names_to = c("var", "df"), names_sep = "\\.") %>% 
  mutate(df = if_else(df == "x", "ref", "df1"),
         var = factor(var, paste0("x", 1:11)))

# now you can plot the data to compare profiles; had to add some formatting to make the graph readable.


ggplot(df, aes(var, value, group = df, colour = df))+
  geom_line()+
  facet_grid(date_ref~date_df1)+
  labs(colour = "Dataset")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 6, angle = 90),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 6),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 6))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: i edited post, so it would be good to get such differences

Comment: @DataMiner could you please  include the variables for determining similarity in your question rather than as an image. Ideally with an explanation of how similarity is defined.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to define first is what criteria of similarity you want to use and what your threshold level of similarity is (how similar the datasets need to be to be considered equivalent). Also the important factor is the nature of your data. For example whether you consider your x1..x11 to be independent or just different samples of the same set.

Depending on the answers it can be anything from comparing each df1[i,2:12] to df2[i,2:12] exactly (if they are just duplicates or not) to comparing both of them to NA and checking if they are both NA or both a known value. Something in between would be checking if the differences of each parameter for each line of the datasets are not greater then 0.05 of the minimal value for example and marking the line equivalent if all the parameters are OK or using something like Pearson's correlation coefficient (`cor(x,y)` function has it enabled by default) for each line and comparing its value to 0.5 for example (both 0.05 and 0.5 are just arbitrary numbers of course and they probably need to be adjusted somewhat). Or maybe the amount of matching points (compared exactly as integers or just similar to some degree) is a better indication for you. There are also known standard tests for sample group dissimilarities, time series dissimilarities, or other statistical hypothesis. Many of them are available in R from bundled packages and if you fancy something else then it is most likely already available in one of the extra packages you can easily download and install.